# if [ $? -ne 0 ] then syntax error then unexpected

Tags: unix, function, if-statement, return-value, ksh

I have been trying to execute the following UNIX shell script which is not working.
I am running it by KornShell (ksh).

```
echo $?;
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
 failed $LINENO-2 $5 $6
fi
failed()
{
        echo "$0 failed at line number $1";
 echo "moving $2 to failed folder"
}
```

This is giving an error saying `Syntax error:then unexpected.`. Basically I have to check for the last executed ksh script's highest/last statement's return code and if it is not equal to zero I have to call function failed with the given parameters. I tried putting semicolon before then but that also did not work.

Can you please help?

**Edit1:** Based on the inputs I changed code. Still the same problem exists.

```
ksh ../prescript/Pre_process $1 $2 $3
rc=$?;
if [[ $rc -ne 0 ]];then
    echo "failed";
       exit 1;
```

**Edit2:**
It is working for the then part by using double squared brackets. I feel I used code of bash script for ksh. I am facing problem in function call of failed. Please let me know appropriate way of function call in ksh for this example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like bash rather than ksh

```
failed() {  
  echo "$0 failed at line number $1";  
  echo "moving $2 to failed folder"  
}

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
  failed $LINENO-2 $5 $6  
fi
```

Comment: can you please let me know how can i make it work on korn shell.

Comment: thanks its working for then part but i am facing different problem with "failed" function call. can you please tell me korn shell way of calling function

Comment: You need to define the function before calling it - edited reply

Answer (score 5):

You need to be careful. The first operation on `$?` will usually clear it so that your `if` won't work anyway.

You would be better off using:

```
rc=$?
echo $rc
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
:
```

Other than that, it works fine for me:

```
$ grep 1 /dev/null

$ if [ $? -ne 0 ]
> then
> echo xx
> fi
xx

$ grep 1 /dev/null

$ echo $?;
1

$ if [ $? -ne 0 ]
> then
> echo yy
> fi
$ _
```

Note the lack of output in the last one. That's because the `echo` has sucked up the return value and overwritten it (since the echo *was* successful).

> As an aside, you should let us know which UNIX and which ksh you're actually using. My working version is ksh93 under Ubuntu. Your mileage may vary if you're using a lesser version.

---

It looks like, from your update, your only problem now is the function call. That's most likely because you're defining it *after* using it. The script:

```
grep 1 /dev/null
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
        failed $rc
fi

failed()
{
        echo Return code was $1
}
```

produces:

```
qq.ksh[6]: failed: not found
```

while:

```
failed()
{
        echo Return code was $1
}

grep 1 /dev/null
rc=$?
if [ $rc -ne 0 ]
then
        failed $rc
fi
```

produces

```
Return code was 1
```

Comment: I checked that but atleast for getting in the zero value as $? i used echo on top. Still my problem is then not working. Is there any thing to do for making it work on ksh

Answer (score 0):

you are missing semicolons at the end of the lines:

```
if [ $? -ne 0]; then
   # …
```

Comment: That's only if you put `then` on the same line. Putting it on  a separate line is fine.

Comment: yeah. I kept ; before then as shown above then it didnt work so i went back to new line then